# Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<T, any Error> in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am new to combine . I created an generic function which return AnyPublisher with result (T) and Error(Service error) it the custom error message . I have the pass the urlSession with dataTaskPublisher and return the request. I am getting following error ..

**Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<T, any Error>' to return type 'AnyPublisher<T, ServiceError>'**

Here is the code for URL request.

```
extension URLRequest {
    static func getRequest(client: ServiceClient) ->URLRequest? {
        guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(string:client.baseUrl + client.path) else {
            return nil
        }
        urlComponents.query = "\(client.params)"
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
            return nil
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = client.method
        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

Here is the code ..

```
class ServiceImpl: Service {

    let urlSesson = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

    func fetchData<T:Codable>(client: ServiceClient, type:T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<T,ServiceError> {

        guard let request = URLRequest.getRequest(client: client) else {
            return Fail(outputType: type, failure: ServiceError.requestNotCreated(message: Constants.requestNotCreated)).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        return urlSesson.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .tryMap {
                guard let response = $0.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                    throw ServiceError.errorWith(message: Constants.noResponse)
                }
                return $0.data
            }
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the error ..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to return a `Publisher` whose `Failure` type is `ServiceError`, but your Combine pipeline can throw other error types as well. `tryMap`'s `Failure` type is `any Error`, same as `decode`'s.

To resolve the problem, you need to call `mapError` to ensure that you are always emitting a `ServiceError` in case of `Failure`.

```
  ...
  .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
  .mapError { error -> ServiceError in
    switch error {
    case let serviceError as ServiceError:
      return serviceError
    default:
      return .generic(error)
    }
  }
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Above code assumes that your `ServiceError` has a `generic(Error)` case. You can return any other case as well, I've just used this as an example since you haven't actually included your `ServiceError` definition in your question.

```
enum ServiceError: Error {
  case errorWith(message: String)
  case generic(Error)
}
```